# Create Like Button under a Tableview Footerview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I create a Like button just (like the FaceBook like or Twitter) inside of a tableview footer using PFRelation but for some reason when any user pressed the Button nothing happened in the app or parse ,help please any ideas .Thank you in advance

```
     -(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section{
         static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"section";
          UITableViewCell *section = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

       UIButton *LikeButton =(UIButton *) [section viewWithTag:1];
        UITapGestureRecognizer *gesture=[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(taponbutton:)];
        [LikeButton setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
           [LikeButton addGestureRecognizer:gesture];
         [section addSubview:LikeButton];
       return section;
        }

           -(void)taponbutton:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gesture{
     PFUser *user=[PFUser currentUser];
      PFObject *object =[object objectForKey:@"newspaper"];

     PFRelation *relation=[object relationForKey:@"like"];
     [object saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
    if(succeeded)
    {

        [relation addObject:object];
        [user saveInBackground];

    }
       }];

     }


         -(void)getthelikequery{

      PFQuery * query=[PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"like"];
      [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
              if(objects)

               {
              for (int i=0;i<_arrayofobjects.count;i++ )
        {

                self.arrayofobjects=objects;

        }
          _arrayofobjects.count;
        UILabel *label=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(133, 12, 42, 21)];
        label.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)_arrayofobjects.count];
        // this label needs to return the #of people who like the article 

    }
}];

    }
```

Comment: Why are you adding a gesture recognizer to a button? Button's already respond to touch, so why do that? Also, apparently section already has a button (since you access it with viewWithTag:), so why are you adding another one (and if the view is reused, you'll be adding yet another one)?

Comment: once the button was tap it will execute the code block

Comment: That doesn't answer my questions. Button's have an action method that they fire when you touch them -- you don't need to add a gesture recognizer to do that.

Comment: can you edit my code i am struggling with this Like Button and Comment

Comment: Sorry, no, I'm not going to write your code for you. You need to take the time to learn the basics.

Comment: sorry for wasting your time but thanks

Answer (score 0):

As per your code. you don't have to add tapgesture on button . you should add target on button.

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 44.0;
}

-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView *viewHeader = [[UIView alloc]init];
    viewHeader.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44.0);//set frame here
    viewHeader.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    //create like button
    UIButton * likeButton = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(65.0,10.0, 320.0-130.0, 30.0)];//set your frame here
    likeButton.tag = section;
    [likeButton setTitle:@"Like" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [likeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(taponbutton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [viewHeader addSubview:likeButton];
    return viewHeader;
}

// Implement Like button.
-(void)taponbutton:(UIButton *)likeButton
{
    NSLog(@"%ld",(long)likeButton.tag);
    // now do what you want. here you'll get your section.
}
```

Maybe this will help you.

Comment: i am trying to implement the button in the footer view